# My if function is not working

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have thousands of lines with duplicate codes, I need to keep the codes with the T modifier only.

```
=IF(B6146="blank",delete,IF(B6146="T",keep))
```

```
Code ID     Modifier     Description
70002                    PNEUMOENCEPHALOGRAPHY;SPRV 
70002       TC           PNEUMOENCEPHALOGRAPHY;SPRV
```

Comment: Please be more detailed with a better sample of your data.

Comment: Please improve the entire question. Are the columns you're showing us Columns `A`, `B`, and `C`? Are they all raw data (i.e., *entered* data)? Where is the formula? Describe much more clearly — ***and*** show an example of — what result you want. What result are you getting now? Do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

As commented, your question isn't clear enough what you have and what you want to do.

But if you want a formula in column D to say Keep or Delete based on if column B contains a "T", then you should use the formula (in D2):

```
=IF(B2="","delete",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("T",B2)),"keep"))
```

Like this:
[image]